# jQuery nextUntil, including, not excluding the matched element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

Is there a way to easily do nextUntil, so that the element matched by the selector is included? I have this, which is only fine if there is a previous sibling:

```
$("#content").find("h3:first").prev().nextUntil("ul:last").wrapAll("<div id='collapse'></div>");
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant parts of your HTML markup? This would help us to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Remove `.prev()`, replace `.nextUntil` with `.nextAll` and use `.addBack()` at the end of your selector as shown below:

```
$("#content").find("h3:first").nextAll("ul:last").addBack().wrapAll("<div id='collapse'></div>");
```

Pre 1.8 should use `andSelf` instead of `addBack`

Comment: Had never accepted an answer on this old question. FYI, anyone checking this now:
"andSelf() - Note: This function has been deprecated and is now an alias for .addBack(), which should be used with jQuery 1.8 and later."

Comment: I just discovered this answer today ( 21-07-2017 ) and it helped me on my project , ty

Comment: Thanks for noticing, @MikhailOrlov. I've fixed this edge case.

Comment: The nextUntil() and addBack() having a structure of <h3> following by whatever you want did the trick for me. Now the <h3> and the following is wrapped by a div.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I found was to get the `length` using `nextUntil` (or `prevUntil`), then use `slice()` with this length + 1 on `nextAll()`:

```
var inclusiveNextUntil = $(this).nextUntil( '.some-class' ).length;
var inclusiveNextUntil = $(this).nextAll().slice( 0 , inclusiveNextUntil + 1 );
```

It’s clumsy but it works. HTH

Fwiw [in the nextAll docs Biziclop mentions](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/#comment-73447013) adding `+ *`:

```
$obj.nextUntil('.last-item-to-include + *')
```

but this doesn’t work for me :/

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do. I think it's a bit cleaner than other suggestions.

```
var elearr = $('selector1').nextUntil('selector2');
var lastele = elearr[elearr.length-1];
elearr.push($(lastele).next());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = $("li.start").nextUntil("li.stop");
s = s.add(s.last().next()).add(s.first().prev());
//and do whatever you need to with s
```

The most intuitive, I think. All made with jQuery methods.
No need to search twice. Easy to understand and easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

I think correct answer is

```
$("#content").find("h3:first").nextUntil("ul:last").addSelf().wrapAll("<div id='collapse'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered by others, using `.addSelf()` is the solution for making the starting element inclusive.

```
$("#content").find("h3:first").nextUntil("ul:last").addSelf().wrapAll("<div id='collapse'></div>");
```

And to make the ending element inclusive, using the `.nextUntil(".class + *")` method solved the issue.

```
$("#content").find("h3:first").nextUntil("ul:last + *").addSelf().wrapAll("<div id='collapse'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `nextUntil()`method takes 2 arguments, "selector" and "filter", so you can do something like

```js
$('something').nextUntil('.stop', '.include-me-only');
```

Answer (score -1):

of course you can, just use jQuery [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).

'nextAll' will include the following elements matching that selector.

while 'nextUntil' exclude the matching selector element.

Comment: "next" just gets the single following sibling, whereas I am grabbing all the siblings up until a defined end-point.

Comment: -1: from nextAll() ref: Get all **following** siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector. , so this will **not** include the matched element.